# Typhoon DI framework produces "ambiguous reference" error

Tags: swift2, xcode7, typhoon

I am building an iOS app and using Typhoon framework for dependency injection. I currently have the framework included by source (ie. git submodule), and the `Typhoon.framework` is linked to my compiled binary. However, when I try to create my first assembly, I get the error `Ambiguous reference to member 'withClass'` which highlights the `TyphoonDefinition` class:

[image: assembly function, with highlight shown]

Looking at error details, I see these three "candidates" found. I'm lost as to why it thinks there are three different kinds of TyphoonDefinition, if that's indeed what this means:

[image]

Any ideas as to how to either (1) resolve the ambiguity, or (2) get more information about the "candidates", the error, or anything else?

Comment: update: I have also tried adding Typhoon as a CocoaPods dependency with the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to have been some kind of build artifact issue that persisted between my attempt to deploy Typhoon with Carthage and then later as a subproject (I decided against using Carthage because one of my other deps was only available via CocoaPods, and this issue began when I re-connected Typhoon just via source). I cleaned everything that could be cleaned (build dir, derived data, Xcode caches, etc) and it appears to have gone away.